# How can I implement port forwarding in a Paramiko server?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

A "direct-tcpip" request (commonly known as port-forwarding) occurs when you run SSH as `ssh user@host -L <local port>:<remote host>:<remote port>` and then try to connect over the local port.

I'm trying to implement direct-tcpip on a custom SSH server, and Paramiko offers the `check_channel_direct_tcpip_request` in the `ServerInterface` class in order to check if the "direct-tcpip" request should be allowed, which can be implemented as follows:

```
class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    # ...
    def check_channel_direct_tcpip_request(self, chanid, origin, destination):
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
```

However, when I use the aforementioned SSH command, and connect over the local port, nothing happens, probably because I need to implement the connection handling myself.

Reading the documentation, it also appears that the channel is only opened after `OPEN_SUCCEDED` has been returned.

How can I handle the direct-tcpip request after returning `OPEN_SUCCEEDED` for the request?

Answer (score 1):

You indeed do need to set up your own connection handler.  This is a lengthy answer to explain the steps I took - some of it you will not need if your server code already works.  The whole running server example in its entirety is here: https://controlc.com/25439153

I used the Paramiko example server code from here https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py as a basis and implanted some socket code on that.  This does not have any error handling, thread related niceties or anything else "proper" for that matter but it allows you to use the port forwarder.

This also has a lot of things you do not need as I did not want to start tidying up a dummy example code. Apologies for that.

To start with, we need the forwarder tools. This creates a thread to run the "tunnel" forwarder. This also answers to your question where you get your channel. You `accept()` it from the transport but you need to do that in the forwarder thread. As you stated in your OP, it is not there yet in the `check_channel_direct_tcpip_request()` function but it will be eventually available to the thread.

```
def tunnel(sock, chan, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
        r, w, x = select.select([sock, chan], [], [])

        if sock in r:
            data = sock.recv(chunk_size)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            chan.send(data)

        if chan in r:
            data = chan.recv(chunk_size)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            sock.send(data)

    chan.close()
    sock.close()


class ForwardClient(threading.Thread):
    daemon = True
    # chanid = 0

    def __init__(self, address, transport, chanid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.socket = socket.create_connection(address)
        self.transport = transport
        self.chanid = chanid

    def run(self):
        while True:
            chan = self.transport.accept(10)
            if chan == None:
                continue

            print("Got new channel (id: %i).", chan.get_id())

            if chan.get_id() == self.chanid:
                break

        peer = self.socket.getpeername()
        try:
            tunnel(self.socket, chan)
        except:
            pass
```

Back to the example server code. Your server class needs to have transport as a parameter, unlike in the example code:

```
class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    # 'data' is the output of base64.b64encode(key)
    # (using the "user_rsa_key" files)
    data = (
    b"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAyO4it3fHlmGZWJaGrfeHOVY7RWO3P9M7hp"
    b"fAu7jJ2d7eothvfeuoRFtJwhUmZDluRdFyhFY/hFAh76PJKGAusIqIQKlkJxMC"
    b"KDqIexkgHAfID/6mqvmnSJf0b5W8v5h2pI/stOSwTQ+pxVhwJ9ctYDhRSlF0iT"
    b"UWT10hcuO4Ks8="
    )
    good_pub_key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(data))

    def __init__(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.event = threading.Event()
```

Then you will override the relevant method and create the forwarder there:

```
def check_channel_direct_tcpip_request(self, chanid, origin, destination):
    print(chanid, origin, destination)
    f = ForwardClient(destination, self.transport, chanid)
    f.start()

    return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
```

You need to add transport parameter to the creation of the server class:

```
t.add_server_key(host_key)
server = Server(t)
```

This example server requires you to have a RSA private key in the directory named test_rsa.key.  Create any RSA key there, you do not need it but I did not bother to strip the use of it off the code.

You can then run your server (runs on port 2200) and issue

```
ssh -p 2200 -L 2300:www.google.com:80  robey@localhost
```

(password is foo)

Now when you try

```
telnet localhost 2300
```

and type something there, you will get a response from Google.

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, is there a reason you're checking if the ID of the channel from `transport.accept()` is equal to `chanid`?

Comment: It was mostly for debugging.  Theoretically there could be a need for this if your client connection created two or more forwarders on one go. It would be useful to ensure you are forwarding the right thing.  You will get the correct id as a parameter to `check_channel_direct_tcpip_request()` and you can use this for verification and added security.   I have never quite understood why Paramiko works this way but it is what it is.

Comment: The answer is in the right direction but still has an issue; the ForwardClient apparently sometimes ends up sending data to the shell channel instead of the direct-tcpip channel, or sends the data for direct-tcpip channel 1 to direct-tcpip channel 2, and so on. It's probably because we're indiscriminately `accept()`ing all channels from the transport. I'll see if I can find something better and update this answer accordingly.

Comment: The channel id check should avoid that from happening. If it accepts a wrong channel, it should just keep accepting some more.   It might be useful to add a check when accepting the shell channel that you actually got that (always chanid 0?) instead of something else. You could test by adding a short sleep to ForwardClient before accepting anything there - if there is a race condition, sleep(0.5) or something like that should ensure for testing purposes that shell channel always get accepted first. Just a guess, though.